# Writing Structural Expectations with Jest

Tags: graphql, jestjs

I am looking to write what I am calling structural expectations with Jest and I am not sure how this could be accomplished.

To start I have a graphql server and a database with a number of todo items. I currently have the following test that just returns true if the content within the database is the same as the response that I have written. I want to check instead that the response looks like an object with data that could be anything.

Here is the code that I have:

```
describe('To Do:', () => {
    it('add todo items', async () => {
        const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/graphql', {
            query: `
                query {
                    getTodoItems {
                        message
                        id
                        dateCreated
                        dateDue
                    }
                }
            `
        });

        const { data } = response;
        expect(data).toMatchObject({
            data: {
                getTodoItems: [
                    {
                      message: "message",
                      id: "5bd9aec8406e0a2170e04494",
                      dateCreated: "1540992712052",
                      dateDue: "1111111111"
                    },
                    {
                      message: "message",
                      id: "5bd9aeec60a9b2579882a308",
                      dateCreated: "1540992748028",
                      dateDue: "1111111111"
                    },
                    {
                      message: "new message",
                      id: "5bd9af15922b27236c91837c",
                      dateCreated: "1540992789836",
                      dateDue: "1111111111"
                    }
                  ]
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Now I want to write something like this, where there can be any number of returned items and they follow similar structuring:

```
describe('To Do:', () => {
    it('add todo items', async () => {
        const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/graphql', {
            query: `
                query {
                    getTodoItems {
                        message
                        id
                        dateCreated
                        dateDue
                    }
                }
            `
        });

        const { data } = response;
        expect(data).toMatchObject({
            data: {
                getTodoItems: [
                    {
                      message: expect.any(String),
                      id: expect.any(String),
                      dateCreated: expect.any(String),
                      dateDue: expect.any(String)
                    } // There needs to be unlimited additional items here
                  ]
            }
        })
    });
});
```

I have been looking throught the docs and I even tried nesting the expectations but I can't seem to get the desired response. Let me know what yo think or if I can clarify in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the best way for me to do it. I would love to hear better answers. I wrote a function within the scope of the test as a jest.fn and then I called it. In that function, I made custom checks to parse the data that was received in the response. From there I added an expect function with the 'toHaveReturnedWith' method to see what the response of my custom function was and finishing out the test.

```
const addTodoResponse = jest.fn(() => {
    // Custom parsing and check here
    // Returns true or false
});

addTodoResponse();

expect(addTodoResponse).toHaveReturnedWith(true);
```

Are there better ways to do this out there?